# SimpleXMLElement Error: Multiple times!

Tags: php, xml

I have found these errors in my error log:

```
[05-Aug-2009 12:57:27] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: ^ in /home/mojo/public_html/shackupload.php on line 37
```

The funny thing is I had about 200 of the above in my error log all with the same timestamp! What is going on and why so many?!

The lines in question is this:

```
if(!(substr($res, 0, 6)=='Failed')){

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($res) or die('Error creating a SimpleXML instance');
    $imagelink = (string) $xml->image_link; // This is the image link
    $_SESSION['shack_link'] = $imagelink;
    echo 'done';    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [SimpleXMLElement::__construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-construct.php) says (quoting) :

> **Errors/Exceptions**
>
> Produces an `E_WARNING` error message
>   for each error found in the XML data
>   and throws an exception if errors were
>   detected.

So, I'd say you tried to load a file that contains XML errors (a non-valid file, for instance).

And to explain the fact you got 200 errors at the same time : you must have something like 200 errors in your file, as `__construct` generates one `E_WARNING` per error in the XML data.

Logging the XML data to a file, in such situation, might help you finding precisely what caused the warnings... At least if that doesn't happen often.

EDIT : BTW, looking at your error_log once in a while is really a good idea ! I don't see enough people doing that :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing out $res before that block of code. It looks like your $res string contains a caret ^ at the beginning or somewhere outside of the markup.